# Perl - Use of uninitialized value in string

Tags: perl

I started teaching myself Perl, and with the help of some Googling, I was able to throw together a script that would print out the file extensions in a given directory. The code works well, however, it will sometimes complain the following:

```
Use of uninitialized value $exts[xx] in string eq at get_file_exts.plx
```

I tried to correct this by initializing my array as follows: my @exts = (); but this did not work as expected.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; 
use warnings;
use File::Find;

#Check for correct number of arguments
if(@ARGV != 1) {
    print "ERROR: Incorrect syntax...\n";
    print "Usage: perl get_file_exts.plx <Directory>\n";
    exit 0;
}

#Search through directory
find({ wanted => \&process_file, no_chdir => 1 }, @ARGV);

my @exts;

sub process_file {
    if (-f $_) {
        #print "File: $_\n";
        #Get extension
        my ($ext) = $_ =~ /(\.[^.]+)$/;

        #Add first extension
        if(scalar @exts == 0) {
            push(@exts, $ext);
        }

        #Loop through array
        foreach my $index (0..$#exts) {
            #Check for match
            if($exts[$index] eq $ext) {
                last;
            } 
            if($index == $#exts) {
                push(@exts, $ext);
            }
        }
    } else {
        #print "Searching $_\n";
    }
}

#Sort array
@exts = sort(@exts);

#Print contents
print ("@exts", "\n");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning is complaining about a content of `$exts[xx]`, not `@exts` itself.

Actually `$ext` can be `undef`, when the filename doesn't match to your regexp, for instance *README*.

Try like:

```
    my ($ext) = $_ =~ /(\.[^.]+)$/ or return;
```

Comment: That is half of the problem and a poor solution.

Answer (score 3):

You need to test if you found an extension.

Also, you should not be indexing your array. You also do not need to manage 'push' just do it. It is not the Perl way. Your for loop should start like this:

```
sub process_file {
  if (-f $_) {
    #print "File: $_\n";
    #Get extension
    my ($ext) = $_ =~ /(\.[^.]+)$/;

    # If we found an extension, and we have not seen it before, add it to @exts
    if ($ext) {
      #Loop through array to see if this is a new extension
      my $newExt = 1;
      for my $seenExt (@exts) {
        #Check for match
        if ($seenExt eq $ext) {
          $newExt = 0
          last;
        }
      }

      if ($newExt) {
        push @exts,$ext;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But what you really want to do is to use a hash table to record if you saw an extension

```
# Move this before find(...); if you want to initialize it or you will clobber the 
# contents
my %sawExt;

sub process_file {
  if (-f $_) {
    #print "File: $_\n";
    # Get extension
    my ($ext) = $_ =~ /(\.[^.]+)$/;

   # If we have an extension, mark that we've seen it
   $sawExt{$ext} = 1
     if $ext;
  }
}

# Print the extensions we've seen in sorted order
print join(' ',sort keys %sawExt) . "\n";
```

Or even

```
sub process_file {
  if (-f $_ && $_ =~ /(\.[^.]+)$/) {
    $sawExt{$1} = 1;
  }
}
```

Or

```
sub process_file {
  $sawExt{$1} = 1
    if -f && /(\.[^.]+)$/;
}
```

Once you start thinking in Perl this is the natural way to write it

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that you aren't accounting for file names that don't contain a dot, so

```
my ($ext) = $_ =~ /(\.[^.]+)$/;
```

sets `$ext` to `undef`.

Despite the warning, processing continues by evaluating `undef` as the null string, failing to find that in `@exts`, and so percolating `undef` to the array as well.

The minimal change to get your code working is to replace

```
my ($ext) = $_ =~ /(\.[^.]+)$/;
```

with

```
return unless /(\.[^.]+)$/;
my $ext = $1;
```

But there is a couple of Perl lessons to be learned here. It *used* to be taught that good programs were well-commented programs. That was in the days of having to write efficient but incomprehensible code, but is no longer true. You should write code that is as clear as possible, and add comments only if you absolutely have to write something that isn't self-explanatory.

You should remember and use Perl idioms, and try to forget most  C that you knew. For instance, Perl accepts the "here document" syntax, and it is common practice to use `or` and `and` as short-circuit operators. Your parameter check becomes

```
@ARGV or die <<END;
ERROR: Incorrect syntax...
Usage: perl get_file_exts.plx <Directory>
END
```

Perl allows for clear but concise programming. This is how I would have written your `wanted` subroutine

```
sub process_file {

  return unless -f and /(\.[^.]+)$/;

  my $ext = $1;

  foreach my $index (0 .. $#exts) {
    return if $exts[$index] eq $ext;
  }

  push @exts, $ext;
}
```

Comment: or consider using a hash instead of `@exts`, if order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`exists`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exists.html) on `$exts[xx]` before accessing it.

`exists` is deprecated though as @chrsblck pointed out :

> Be aware that calling exists on array values is deprecated and likely
>   to be removed in a future version of Perl.

But you should be able to check if it exists (and not `0` or `""`) simply with :

```
if($exts[index] && $exts[$index] eq $ext){
   ...
}
```

Comment: The perldoc warns against it's use on arrays: " Be aware that calling exists on array values is deprecated and likely to be removed in a future version of Perl."

Comment: @chrsblck Is the suggested replacement simply to use `if($exts[xx])`?

Comment: Yes. You can also use `defined`. But you need to keep in mind that `0` and `""` (zero-length string) are in fact `defined`.

Comment: Re *"exists is deprecated"*: But only when used on ***array*** values, right?